# How to run Android Wear app on Watch from Android Studio?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

From Android Studio, I'm trying to launch an app on an LGE G Watch F5CC (Android 6.0.1, Android Wear 1.5.0)

I can see the watch in Android Studio's "Select Deployment Target" window, but the device is greyed out, with the message

> missing uses-feature watch, non-watch apks cannot be launched on a
>   watch

NOTE: The app is not a standalone app for watch. It's supposed to run as a companion to the main app.

In the wear app's AndroidManifest.xml, I've the following statement:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Can you post your entire manifest file please? Also check your run configuration and make sure that you're not trying to launch a non-wear activity.

Comment: Actually you are right, the main activity in the wear's manifest is a non-wear activity. The wear app is supposed to run with the main app on the smartphone, and sync data from it. But still, how can I deploy this companion app on the watch from Android Studio ?

Comment: What build configuration have you set? Does it say "app" or "wear" ?

Comment: Do you mean the "Run configuration" ? It is under Android App. I have a wear module whose manifest include the line <uses-feature       
 android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />. It seems the wear module is included in the main app apk, but how can I load it on the watch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my wear module was not included in the project's settings.gradle file.

Adding the wear module to this file solved the problem:

```
include ':...', ':wear'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out `android:required="false"`, so that your manifest line just reads like this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>
```

In my Android Studio, `android:required="false"` is flagged as not allowed on that element. And logically, if this is a Wear OS app, it is required to run on a watch anyway.